# Import error open for cvlibrary-python

Tags: python, opencv

Can anyone explain what does this error means and what I have to do to fix it?[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fjU5.jpg)

Comment: Before writing up any post in SO, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Install 64 bit version of cv2.

*P.S. I would recommend that you go through the guidelines for writing good questions on SO.*